# Are there Shadow Groups" like there are Light Groups?

Tags: light, groups, shadows

Im having a problem where I only want an object cast shadows on itself, with one light group. I have two separate light groups, and two light source, but the objects still seem to cast shadows onto other objects. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I'd recommend using [renderlayers](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html) to split up your scene, then use the [compositor](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/index.html) to recombine the results. The exact setup will likely depend on which render engine you're using