# How to separate light in the same scene?

Tags: rendering

I made an indoor room scene. This scene is rendered with EEVEE and all material used are Principled BSDF.

Yellow light makes the scene looks yellow, however, I use a Toon shader to make the character, and the character's light is used *Separate RGB* node.

So if I want to light the character for the main light, I use a red light for my character, the red will affect the scene.

I search on Youtube to find a way to separate the light, but it didn't work. I want to know why.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, could you explain that a bit simpler? Are you saying you want to use a red (point) light to light your character, but don't want it to color the rest of the scene red?

Comment: Yes! This is what I want.red light only affect character

Comment: I think the easiest way would probably be to do 2 separate renders - one of the scene without the character, and another with just the (red) lit character, and then put them together in the compositor.

Comment: "*I search on Youtube to find a way to separate the light, but it didn't work. I want to know why.*" How can we know? What have you tried which tutorial did you follow? What steps did you take?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184796/a-way-to-give-objects-their-own-lights https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45668/are-there-shadow-groups-like-there-are-light-groups